# How do I throw Exception again and catch it

Tags: php, exception, model-view-controller

I want to put a message in my $message member if an exception is thrown from my model.

I got the exception to the controller but i don't know how to catch it in the view.

Here is a example of what I am trying to create.

```
// This is in my controller //
try {
    if ($this->registerModel->doRegister($credentials) == true) {
        echo "success";
    }
} catch (userAlreadyExistException $e){
    throw $e; // I want this to my view
}

// This is in my Model //
public function doRegister($credential)
{
    if(true){
        throw new userAlreadyExistException();
    }
    return true;
}

// This is my view //
public function getExceptions(){

    try{

    } catch (userAlreadyExistException $e) {
        $this->message = "User already exist in the database";
    }

//I also have this in a own class
class userAlreadyExistException extends Exception {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution with interface as a listener.

```
// Create a new interface //
interface IregisterListener
{
    public function myIFunction($listener);
}

// This is in my Model //
public function doRegister($credential ,IregisterListener $listener)
{
    if($credential == false){
        $listener->myIFunction("something whent wrong");
    }
    return true;
}

// This is in my View //
class myView implements IregisterListener
{
    public function myIFunction($listener)
    {
        $message = "User exists, pick another username.";
    }
}
```